# Using Parseval's identity to find $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{S(2\sqrt{n}) \cdot C(2\sqrt{n})}{n^3}$

Tags: summation, special-functions, fresnel-integrals

I would like to find the sum:

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{S(2\sqrt{n}) \cdot C(2\sqrt{n})}{n^3}$$

where $ S(n)$ and  $C(n)$ denote the Sine and Cosine Fresnel Integrals respectively. But somewhere in my work i've made a mistake (maybe several) and I would like to know where I went awry.

**My work**:

To start I use Parseval's identity which states:

$$2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_n|^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|^2 \space dx$$

where

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cdot e^{-inx}\space dx$$

I consider the function:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})$$

$c_n$ becomes:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})) \cdot e^{-inx}\space dx$$

This integral is quite difficult for me, so I plugged it into wolfram alpha and found:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{(-1)^n \sqrt{i\pi}}{2n^{3/2}} \cdot (erfi(\sqrt{2\pi in}) + i\cdot erf(\sqrt{2\pi in}) ) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \frac{(-1)^n (1+i)}{n^{3/2}}\cdot (erfi(\sqrt{2\pi in}) + i\cdot erf(\sqrt{2\pi in}) )$$

where $erf(x)$ and $erfi(x)$ are the error function and imaginary error function respectively.

$g(n) = erfi(\sqrt{2\pi in}) + i\cdot erf(\sqrt{2\pi in}) $ is a complex function with a real and imaginary part, but I believe that:

$$g(n) = erfi(\sqrt{2\pi in}) + i\cdot erf(\sqrt{2\pi in})=
\begin{cases}
 2i \cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n})) &\text{if }\, n\gt 0\\
 2 \cdot (C(2\sqrt{-n}) - S(2\sqrt{-n})) &\text{if }\, n\lt 0\\
      0 &\text{n = 0}
\end{cases} $$

So putting everything together I get that:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \frac{(-1)^n (1+i)}{n^{3/2}}\cdot \begin{cases}
 2i \cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n})) &\text{if }\, n\gt 0\\
 2 \cdot (C(2\sqrt{-n}) - S(2\sqrt{-n})) &\text{if }\, n\lt 0\\
      0 &\text{n = 0}
\end{cases}$$

simplifying a little gives:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}} \cdot \frac{(-1)^n (1+i)}{n^{3/2}}\cdot \begin{cases}
 i \cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n})) &\text{if }\, n\gt 0\\
  C(2\sqrt{-n}) - S(2\sqrt{-n}) &\text{if }\, n\lt 0\\
      0 &\text{n = 0}
\end{cases}$$

I think that:

$$ |c_n|^2 = \frac{1}{8\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot \begin{cases}
 2 \cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n}))^2 &\text{if }\, n\gt 0\\
 2 \cdot (C(2\sqrt{-n}) - S(2\sqrt{-n}))^2 &\text{if }\, n\lt 0\\
      0 &\text{n = 0}
\end{cases}$$

now plugging this result into parseval's identity gives:

$$2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{8\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot 2 \cdot (C(2\sqrt{-n}) - S(2\sqrt{-n}))^2 + 2\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{8\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot 2 \cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n}))^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx$$

simplifying gives:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{-n}) - S(2\sqrt{-n}))^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n}))^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx$$

for the first sum on the left hand side I make the substitution -n = t and can then rewrite the left hand side as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{t^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{t}) - S(2\sqrt{t}))^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n}))^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx$$

i replace the dummy variable t with n and rewrite once more:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) - S(2\sqrt{n}))^2 +  \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{n}) + S(2\sqrt{n}))^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx$$

all terms on the left hand side should cancel except for the mixed terms giving:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot 4(C(2\sqrt{n})S(2\sqrt{n})) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx$$

So I get that:

$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{n})S(2\sqrt{n})) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx$$

Wolfram alpha says that

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{x + \pi} - (i\cdot\sqrt{x-\pi})|^2 \space dx  = \pi^2 \cdot (4 + \pi)$$

which would mean that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot (C(2\sqrt{n})S(2\sqrt{n})) = \frac{\pi^2}{2} \cdot (4 + \pi)$$

however, when I checked the left hand sum on wolfram alpha the sum is ~0.207871 while $\frac{\pi^2}{2} \cdot (4 + \pi) ~ 35.242$

I can't tell where I made a mistake in my work, could I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

Take care ! In Mathematica (and then Wolfram Alpha)
$$S(z)=\int_0^z \sin \left(\frac{\pi  }{2}t^2\right)\,dt\qquad C(z)=\int_0^z \cos\left(\frac{\pi  }{2}t^2\right)\,dt$$ and not
$$S(z)=\int_0^z \sin \left(t^2\right)\,dt\qquad C(z)=\int_0^z \cos\left(t^2\right)\,dt$$

This explains the difference you observe.